# How to export TFRecords from pts label files for tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: tensorflow, bounding-box, object-detection-api, tfrecord

usually when we generate TFRecords from xml label files (from labelimg for example), there are the values of x.min, x.max, y.min and y.max, which show a square label.
we can make a CSV data out of it and generate the TFRecords from it.

but in the case of pts, the values are as a non-square bounding box, e.g:

`bounding_box: 534.588998862  232.095176337; 101.596234357  388.45367463; 51.3295676906  249.25367463; 484.322332196 92.8951763367`

so there is four x and y points, not just two as the labelimg gives.
can someone explain to me how generate TFRecord from pts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just in case anyone else had the same question, i wrote a script that'll make those four points as a square with xmin xmax ymin ymax, so we can get the tfrecord easily as like from xml labelimg.

here it is:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import csv

for pts_file in glob.glob("./labels" + '/*.pts'):
    with open(pts_file) as f:
        im=Image.open("./img/" + pts_file[9:-3] + "jpg")
        filename = pts_file[9:-3] + "jpg"
        width = str(im.size[0])
        height = str(im.size[1])
        classs = "fish"
        lines = f.readlines() 
        content = [line.split(' ')for line in open (pts_file)]
        xmax = max(int(float(content[0][1])), int(float(content[0][4])), int(float(content[0][7])), int(float(content[0][10])))
        xmin = min(int(float(content[0][1])), int(float(content[0][4])), int(float(content[0][7])), int(float(content[0][10])))
        ymax = max(int(float(content[0][3][0:5])), int(float(content[0][6][0:5])), int(float(content[0][9][0:5])), int(float(content[0][11][0:5])))
        ymin = min(int(float(content[0][3][0:5])), int(float(content[0][6][0:5])), int(float(content[0][9][0:5])), int(float(content[0][11][0:5])))

        fields=[filename,width,height,classs,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]
        with open(r'name', 'a', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(fields)        

print('Successfully converted pts to csv.')
```